# Ovftool error "Unsupported value" when converting a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, converters, vmware, vcenter, ovf

I get some ovf images. And I have a problem when I try to import on vSphere. I was looking at solutions but I could not find it.

When I do a "deploy ovf template" on vCenter, I get an error:

`The OVF package requires unsupported hardware. Detail: line 26 unsupported hardware family 'vmx-08'.`

So I try to use the ovftool to convert a machine. When I try

```
ovftool E:\location\name.ova E:\location\vmx\name.vmx
```

I get a message like this:

```
C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool>ovftool E:\location\name.ova E:\location\vmx\name.vmx Opening OVA source: E:\location\name.ova Opening VMX target: E:\location\vmx\name.vmx Warning:
 - Line 39: Unsupported value '12' for element 'CoresPerSocket'. Error:
 - Line 32: Unsupported value '24' for element 'VirtualQuantity'.
 - Virtual machine has 24 virtual CPUs, but the host only supports 8. The number  of virtual CPUs may be limited by the guest OS selected for the virtual machine  or by the licensing for the host. Completed with errors
```

Maybe I need to use some parameters like numberOfCpus, coresPerSocket, tt or viCpuResource. But I don't know how to use it and I can't find it. When I'm trying to set something I get an error

```
Error: Unknown option: '-coresPerSocket=2'
Completed with errors
```

Specification of server

```
2 socket 
8 CPU per socket
24 GB RAM
ESXi 4.1
```

Specification of my PC

```
i7
Windows 7 64 bit
8 GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem by convert OVA to OVF and after that conversion ovftool created a manifest file and sum control file. I edited the manifest problematic lines and deleted the sum control file. After that my vSphere would apply changes and successfully import the VM.
If you don't delete sum control file Vsphere will show you an error, and if you don't edit the manifest file, Vsphere may don't import that VM.

```
ovftool -tt=OVF E:\location\name.ova E:\location\ovf\
```